# openSSL shows a revoked certificate as secure

Tags: certificates, openssl, x.509, certificate-revocation

I downloaded a revoked certificate from the website https://www.ssl.com/sample-valid-revoked-and-expired-ssl-tls-certificates/. Specifically, the revoked certificate of the site https://revoked-rsa-ev.ssl.com/.

To check the verification result in OpenSSL, I downloaded the CRL and ran the command :

> `openssl verify -untrusted 'SSL.com EV SSL Intermediate CA RSA R3.pem' -CRLfile SSLcom-SubCA-EV-SSL-RSA-4096-R3.crl.pem -show_chain revoked-rsa-ev.ssl.com.pem`

However, instead of showing it as revoked, it successfully verifies the certificate. This is the output :

```
revoked-rsa-ev.ssl.com.pem: OK
Chain:
depth=0: C = US, ST = Texas, L = Houston, O = SSL Corp, serialNumber = NV20081614243, CN = revoked-rsa-ev.ssl.com, postalCode = 77098, businessCategory = Private Organization, street = 3100 Richmond Ave, jurisdictionST = Nevada, jurisdictionC = US (untrusted)
depth=1: C = US, ST = Texas, L = Houston, O = SSL Corp, CN = SSL.com EV SSL Intermediate CA RSA R3 (untrusted)
depth=2: C = US, ST = Texas, L = Houston, O = SSL Corporation, CN = SSL.com EV Root Certification Authority RSA R2
```

Have I used the incorrect command? Moreover, even Chrome shows the certificate as trusted but not Firefox. Why is this happening?

Comment: From `openssl help verify` I suspect (but am not in a position to verify) that you want either `-crl_check` or `-crl_check_all` (and, possibly, `-extended_crl`). My _guess_ is you've loaded the list, but not asked it to actually check for revocation.

Comment: Yes, adding `-crl_check` flag works. Thank you.

Comment: But why does Chrome show it as a valid certificate?

Comment: As (I think) I understand it, checking for revocation requires the browser to check for, and possibly download an up-to-date CRL, which may take a non-negligible time. There's probably a setting to control whether this happens or not.

Comment: [As that CA itself tells you](https://www.ssl.com/article/how-do-browsers-handle-revoked-ssl-tls-certificates/#ftoc-heading-2) **Chrome doesn't use (CA-issued) CRLs**. Also see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55811/how-are-crlsets-more-secure https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180938/revoked-cert-not-showing-revoked-in-chrome-64-0-3282-186 https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/219443/how-well-do-current-browsers-handle-certificate-revocation

Comment: Thank you, that was a pretty fascinating read.